# Can I use data uri's in Chrome for iOS?

Tags: google-chrome, data-uri

I have a web application that uses data uri's to display images. The images display in Google Chrome version 27.0.1453.116 m on a laptop. However, the images do not display on Google Chrome for iOS on an iPad. Are data uri's supported in Google Chrome for iOS?

Comment: What is the dimensions of the image?

Comment: [Looks like you can.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) Could you show what generates the URIs?

Comment: I set the dimensions of the image to 20px x 20px, and also removed any CSS that may have made the image appear off-screen. I am using jQuery $.getJSON to load data. My text elements load properly with $.getJSON, but the image does not load. Instead of using data-uri's, I also tried loading images from the file system, but it still doesn't work. The data is served from an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API. Do I need to have any type of permissions set for images to appear? I am unclear why the images appear on a desktop computer but not on an iPad nor iPod Touch. The text works, the image doesn't appear.

Comment: Once again: could you show what generates the URIs? i.e. the code?

Comment: It is functional now. I debugged it by connecting the iPod to a a Mac and running Safari's developer tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A better test for base64 URI support (can I create a large base64-encoded image in JS?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680539/a-better-test-for-base64-uri-support-can-i-create-a-large-base64-encoded-image)